# Download file from Box

Tags: python, python-2.7, box

I am new to box, trying to upload and download file from the box using boxsdk uploading file is working fine for me. I got stuck with downloading file.

I have written code to download file as follows:

```
with open('destinationfilepath','wb') as file_object:
    client.file('boxfileId').download_to(file_object)
    file_object.close()
```

It's printing content of my file and finally getting error
as `Nonetype object has to attribute 'readline'` leaving with no content in destination file.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stuck with this, I got it working by updating all `pip packages` I had, may be because of version mismatch it was not working.